# Return derived object through base class reference parameter

Tags: c++, c++11, pointers, inheritance

I have a function that takes a reference to a base object (used as an output parameter).  That function must create a derived object and pass it back to the caller through that reference.

The caller calls that function by dereferencing a pointer to base (in this case a smart ptr), and passing it as the argument to the function.

The problem is that even though the function changes the underlying object, the caller still can't cast the pointer to the derived object:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
using namespace std;

struct Base {
  virtual void id() { cout << "Base" << endl; }
};

struct Derived: Base {
  void id() override { cout << "Derived" << endl; }
};

void get_derived(Base &b) {
  b = Derived();
  b.id();         //Still prints "Base"
}

int main() {

  auto b = make_shared<Base>();
  b->id(); //prints "Base"
  get_derived(*b);
  b->id(); //prints "Base" still

  auto f = dynamic_pointer_cast<Derived>(b);
  if(!f) cout << "cast failed" << endl; //this branch taken
  else cout << "cast succeeded" << endl;
}
```

Why is it that after `b = Derived()`, the pointer to `id()` in the virtual table of `b` still points to `Base`'s `id()` function instead of `Derived`'s vtable?  And how do I change `get_derived()` to make the `b` reference refer to a `Derived` object?
Note: I can't change the signature of `get_derived()`

Comment: `b = Derived();` is assigning the value of a default constructed `Derived` to `b`. It does not change what `b` refers to or that object's type. An object's type cannot change at runtime.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux So basically there is no way that `get_derived` can pass a full `Derived` object back to the caller, so I have to make a new function that takes a `shared_ptr<Base>` instead correct?
Something like:
```lang-cpp
void get_derived2(shared_ptr<Base> &b){
  b = make_shared<Derived>();
  b->id();
}
```

Comment: You can change `get_derived` to take a `std::shared_ptr<Base> &` and assign to it to the result of a `std::make_shared<Derived>()`. What that does is create an actual `Derived` and changes what `b` refers to. Edit : Missed your edit. What you wrote seems to be right.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux: Ok thank you!